# Having trouble with pow() in C

Tags: c, exponent

I am currently reading an online version of Stephen Kochan's "Programming in C (3rd Edition)." One of the activities involves evaluating an equation,

> Write a program that evaluates the following expression and displays the results
>   (remember to use exponential format to display the result):
>   (3.31 x 10<sup>-8</sup> x 2.01 x 10<sup>-7</sup>) / (7.16 x 10<sup>-6</sup> + 2.01 x 10<sup>-8</sup>)

When I attempt to do this, the output is always 0.0000. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
float result;
    result = (3.31 * pow(10,-8) * 2.01 * pow(10,-7)) / (7.16 * pow(10,-6) + 2.01 * pow(10, -8));
    printf ("%f", result);
    return 0;
}
```

If I am doing anything wrong, please point it out. If you have any tips, please say so.

Comment: You **must** [enable all compiler warnings and treat them as errors](https://ideone.com/aajezX)

Comment: You have likely misunderstood the question anyway. The "scientific" notation such as `2.01e-7` is perfectly legit in C.

Comment: You should use `double` by default, `float` only when you're extremely memory constrained.

Comment: @tadman .. or if you have an FPU for floats only.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's going to be highly unusual.

Comment: @tadman It's exactly the case on the extremely popular ARM Cortex-M4F

Comment: @EugeneSh. Embedded or mobile environments always have their quirks. This doesn't change the fact that generally `double` is a good default and that `pow` returns `double`.

Comment: "output is always 0.0000" --> Are you sure it was not `"0.000000"?

Comment: What result did you expect?

Comment: It should be simpler than that: `#include <stdio.h> int main(void) { printf("%.16g\n", 3.31e-8 * 2.01e-7 / (7.16e-6 + 2.01e-8)); }` should output `9.266026935558e-10`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must `#include <math.h>`

Also, change to this:

```
printf ("%e\n", result);
```

You should probably also have

```
double result;
```

because `pow()` returns a `double`.

Comment: I did not vote, but it could be because this answer neglects to say that `pow` is not declared. The compiler may have given it an implicit declaration in which it returns `int`. Then the behavior with the real `pow` is undefined. And the fact that `pow` returns a `double` does not mean one should assign its result to a `double`. There are issues of what is truly desired there, but correctness is not a direct issue.

Comment: Not sure why people are hating on it, as it shows the correct value. The default `%f` notation lacks sufficient precision. The answer here is `0.000000000926602693555799825448`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks. I did have that warning, but is that compiler dependent?

Comment: @JohnPerry: Yes, and dependent on the language version or variant. Implicit declarations in C are ancient.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Implicit declarations in C I'm familiar with, and `clang` had warned me. I just wasn't sure if your phrasing "may have given it" meant it always would. (I'm familiar with them but I avoid them so I'm not *that* familiar with them. :-))

Comment: Diwnvoter here. This answer is partially correct (the e format is needed), partially useless (switching to double is harmless but not needed to resolve the problem)  and missing a very (most?) important part (to use `pow`, one must `#include <math.h>`.  The program might still work with some compilers without that last part, though this is non-standard and not guaranteed in any way. So yeah maybe too fast with the downvote.

Comment: What this answer is actually missing, is that there is no reason to use `pow` for this question at all.

Answer (score -1):

Use %e to get an exponent result value as instructed.

```
int main (void)
{
float i;
float j;
float result;
result = i / j;
i = 3.31 * 10 -8 * 2.01 * 10 -7;
j = 7.16 * 10 -6 + 2.01 * 10 -8;
printf("%e", i, j, result);

return 0;
}
```